# Excel 2013: How to copy selective columns form different workbook

Tags: excel, formula, worksheet-function

I have two workbooks;

1)"PIN CODES": -
   Columns are, A)Pincode     B)District C) State

2)"Customers Details": -
   Columns are,     D)Pincode    E)District     f)State

If a pincode in a cell of D(workbook2) matches to the pincode of any cell of A(Workbook1), the respective cell values in B&C should be copied to E&F.

Can anyone help me to find a formula for that??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: So you are trying to fill columns E and F in Customers Details with data from PIN CODES where there is a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you have a table like this in a workbook "PIN CODES" (top left is `A1`):

```
Pin Code    District      State
1           Houston         TX
2           LA              CA
3           Seattle         WA
4           Billings        MO
5           San Francisco   SF
5           Omaha           NE
```

and your second workbook, "Customers Details" has the same table, with only pin codes. You want to fill in this table based off the "PIN CODES" workbook.

In `E1` of "Customers Details", you can use this Index/Match formula:

`=INDEX('[PIN CODES]Sheet1'!B$2:B$7,MATCH($D2,'[PIN CODES]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$7,0))`

Note: Adjust the ranges' rows' from B2:B7 to whatever you need.  You can drag that into `F1` and it'll return the `State` match.

Finally, you can wrap an `IfError()` around that to return a blank (or whatever you want):

`=IFERROR(INDEX('[PIN CODES]Sheet1'!B$2:B$7,MATCH($D2,['PIN CODES]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$7,0)),"No Match")`

Edit: And just for fun, if you wanted to be able to change the header row in your "Customers Details" worksheet and have the info update based on that, you can use this formula:
`=IFERROR(INDEX('[PIN CODES]Sheet1'!$A$2:$C$7,MATCH($D2,'PIN CODES]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$7,0),MATCH(E$1,'[PIN CODES]Sheet1'!$A$1:$C$1,0)),"")`

Comment: Formula worked out well. Thanks for your helping hand

Comment: @Shehanshashefeeq - Glad to help! If this worked, do you mind marking as the Answer?